# How do I solve this PHP-PEAR error / install PEAR on Fedora?

Tags: php, pear, fedora

I'm trying to save an old, failing web-server setup consisting of Fedora, PHP, PEAR, and Oracle.

With some difficulty (I'm very new to all four), I've been able to set up something similar on a newer system. I used Fedora 19, PHP 5.5.4 (with Apache 2.4.6), and Oracle 11g.

That just leaves PEAR.

Now, from what I understand, PEAR is some PHP code, like a library, which PHP Web Applications can use to save time from having to code them again - database connection, for example.

But I don't know what to do with it, or even how to get it. Copy paste from my old system? Download using the CLI using yum? Are there packages I need to be aware of, or is it just a one download-one install thing?

For instance, a basic PHP webpage with the following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

works fine on the new server setup, so I'm assured that everything else is working. But when I try to load the PHP files from the other server, it returns an `Internal Server Error`. I checked the `error_log` files under `/etc/httpd/logs`, and most of the errors appear as below:

`PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'MDB2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/hrweb/includes/functions.php on line 4`

**EDIT:**

According to the PEAR Website, PEAR is included upon the installation of PHP, though not all modules / packages are there. Typing in the command `pear` in the CLI does confirm it is installed, though it does not help the issue.

I got the MDB2 package via **pear install MDB2**, though apparently, MDB2_Driver_oci8 is required. Whenever I try to download that, I get the following:

`"MDB2_Driver_oci8" version "1.4.1" does not have REST XML available`

In addition to this, I also tried to download OLE, which gets me the following:

`No releases available for package "pear.php.net/OLE"`

This was also previously the error of trying to download MDB2_Driver_oci8.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of PEAR are you using? I was able to install both version 1.4.1 and 1.5.0.b4 of the MDB2_Driver_oci8 package without incident... "$pear version" should display the version number for PEAR, PHP and what OS you're using.

Comment: Strange, I get a for loop error in PEAR, but at the end, it does display the version. PEAR version is 1.9.4, PHP is 5.5.5, Zand Engine is 2.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the (surprise!) [MDB2 package](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) to get `MDB2.php`:

```
$ pear install mdb2
```

and the adapter of your choice:

```
$ pear install mdb2_driver_mysql-beta
```

Then make sure the PEAR php directory is in your include path - see the [PEAR manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php).

---

> "MDB2_Driver_oci8" version "1.4.1" does not have REST XML available

try to install the beta version:

```
$ pear install mdb2_driver_oci8-beta
```

---

> No releases available for package "pear.php.net/OLE"

You're trying to install the stable version, but OLE does not have any stable version (yet): http://pear.php.net/package/OLE/download

Append either `-alpha` or `-beta` after OLE:

```
$ pear install OLE-beta
```

Comment: Haha, yes, I got that far, but I did run into other problems. I've updated my question.